# How to increase and decrease count by clicking button in react?

Tags: reactjs, counter, increment, decrement

I want to create a increment and decrement counter but i don't understand the matter please help me

```
 const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState()
      const handleIncrement = () => {
        if (quantity < 20) {
          setQuantity()
        }
      }
      const handleDecrement = () => {
        if (quantity > 1) {
          setQuantity()
        }
      }
```

Comment: I found this codepen online: https://codesandbox.io/s/74qzy90m3x?file=/App.js that might help with your problem!

Comment: React docs have a simple [example](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for increment, you can use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

A sample code for your understanding about react Hooks "useState".
‎

```
function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
  const incrementCounter = () => setCounter(counter + 1);
  let decrementCounter = () => setCounter(counter - 1);
  if(counter<=0) {
    decrementCounter = () => setCounter(1);
  }
  return (
    <div> 
      <ButtonIncrement onClickFunc={incrementCounter}/>
      <Display message={counter}/> 
      <ButtonDecrement onClickFunc={decrementCounter}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0)
      const handleIncrement = () => {
        if (quantity < 20) {
          setQuantity(quantity - 1)
        }
      }
      const handleDecrement = () => {
        if (quantity > 1) {
          setQuantity(quantity + 1)
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

useState hook in react returns a stateful value, and a function to update it. In this case the setQuantity function is used to update the state. It accepts a new state value and enqueues a re-render of the component.

It should be used like this: `setQuantity(newValue);`

Probably the correct way of doing it in your code would be:

```
 const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1)

      const handleIncrement = () => {
        if (quantity < 20) {
          setQuantity(quantity + 1)
        }
      }

      const handleDecrement = () => {
        if (quantity > 1) {
          setQuantity(quantity - 1)
        }
      }
```

I think there are some concepts that you are missing, please take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html if you want to know more :)

Answer (score 0):

You should define a default state first

```
const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0)
```

and after that you can either use the quantity or previous state of the setQuatity function.

```
 const handleIncrement = () => {
      setQuantity(prev=>prev++)
      // or
      setQuantity(quantity++)
    }
  }

 const handleIncrement = () => {
      // add logic to prevent negative count here
      setQuantity(prev=>prev--)
      // or
      setQuantity(quantity--)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

class Test extends Component { state = { count: 1, }

onIncrement = () => { this.setState((prevState) => { return { count: prevState.count + 1 } }) }

onDecrement = () => { this.setState((prevState) => { return { count: prevState.count - 1 } }) }

render() { return ( {this.state.count} Increment Decrement ) } }
```